How do I fix the SwitchCase expression serialization error in Elsa3 workflows?
I'm working with Elsa 3 (latest and greatest) workflows and trying to define a Switch activity with cases that include conditions. However, I'm encountering the following error:

System.NotSupportedException: Serialization and deserialization of 'System.Func`2[[Elsa.Expressions.Models.ExpressionExecutionContext, Elsa.Expressions, Version=3.1.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null],[System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask`1[[System.Object, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]], System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]]' instances is not supported.

Here is the code that causes the error:
protected override void Build(IWorkflowBuilder builder)
{
    var transactionCommandVariable = new Variable<IFlowCommand<TransactionPayload>>();

    builder.Root = new Sequence
    {
        Activities =
        {
            new ReceiveCommandActivity(loggerFactory.CreateLogger<ReceiveCommandActivity>())
            {
                Name = "ReceiveCommand",
                CanStartWorkflow = true,
                Result = new(transactionCommandVariable) // Set the variable to the output of the activity.
            },
            new Switch()
            {
                Cases =
                {
                    new SwitchCase()
                    {
                        Label = "create transaction",
                        Condition = Expression.DelegateExpression(ctx => transactionCommandVariable.Get(ctx) is FlowCommand<CreateTransactionPayload>),
                        Activity = new Sequence
                        {
                            Activities =
                            {
                                new ValidateCreateTransactionCommandActivity(
                                    assetRepository,
                                    walletRepository,
                                    txValidator,
                                    loggerFactory.CreateLogger<ValidateCreateTransactionCommandActivity>())
                                {
                                    Command = new(transactionCommandVariable),
                                },
                                new CreateTransactionActivity(
                                    txnRepository,
                                    mapper,
                                    eventPublisher,
                                    config,
                                    loggerFactory.CreateLogger<CreateTransactionActivity>())
                                {
                                    Command = new(transactionCommandVariable),
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    },

The error message suggests that serialization and deserialization of System.Func instances are not supported. How can I fix the SwitchCase expression so that it works correctly?
Additional Information:

I'm using Elsa version 3.1.3.
The transactionCommandVariable is a workflow variable holding the transaction command.
The condition is supposed to check if the command is of type FlowCommand<CreateTransactionPayload>.

Error is thrown from here:

public class JsonIgnoreCompositeRootConverter : JsonConverter<IActivity>
{
    public override IActivity Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    [UnconditionalSuppressMessage("Trimming", "IL2026:Members annotated with 'RequiresUnreferencedCodeAttribute' require dynamic access otherwise can break functionality when trimming application code", Justification = "<Pending>")]
    public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, IActivity? value, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        writer.WriteStartObject();
        PropertyInfo[] obj = value?.GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public) ?? Array.Empty<PropertyInfo>();
        JsonSerializerOptions options2 = new JsonSerializerOptions(options);
        PropertyInfo[] array = obj;
        foreach (PropertyInfo propertyInfo in array)
        {
            if (propertyInfo.GetCustomAttribute<JsonIgnoreAttribute>() == null && propertyInfo.GetCustomAttribute<JsonIgnoreCompositeRootAttribute>() == null)
            {
                string propertyName = options.PropertyNamingPolicy?.ConvertName(propertyInfo.Name) ?? propertyInfo.Name;
                writer.WritePropertyName(propertyName);
                object value2 = propertyInfo.GetValue(value);
                if (value2 == null)
                {
                    writer.WriteNullValue();
                }
                else
                {
// ERROR
                    JsonSerializer.Serialize(writer, value2, options2);
                }
            }
        }
        writer.WriteEndObject();
    }
}

Any help to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated!
I also went through elsa-core/main github codebase but could not find any unit tests that would help me.

Not sure if this should really be an answer but too long for a comment.
I'm not familiar with elsa workflows and may be completely wrong but this looks suspicious
Condition = Expression.DelegateExpression(ctx => transactionCommandVariable.Get(ctx) is FlowCommand<CreateTransactionPayload>)`

Expressions, like Funcs, are not serializable but one thing they do have over Funcs is that they can be interrogated and with may be converted to something that can easily be expressed in JSON.
Some related questions:

Serialize/Deserialize Expression<Func<T, bool>>[] using Serialize.Linq
Compile Expression at runtime Using Serialize.Linq
Is it possible to serialise a Func or Action to JSON in .Net Core

In particular, this discussion Is it possible to serialise a Func or Action to JSON in .Net Core surfaces a possible solution in Nuqleon.Linq.Expressions.Bonsai.Serialization
Integrating this in to your custom de/serialization may provide a way forward.

Thanks. I managed to remove the dependency on Delegate Expressions and the error went away but the workflow Input/output variables are still not working as expected.

That sounds like it might be a different, albeit related, question. Feel free to ask another question referring to this one.
